# Pequeño Error en Autocomplete en su CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de implementar el Autocomplete, 
Como pueden observar en la imagen el diseño del resultado no aparece donde tendría que aparecer en este caso en el input que se muestra

**Adjunto mi codigo `HTML` y `jquery`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="autocomplete/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css"/>  
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="autocomplete/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>            
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="hidden" id="numero_unico"> 
    <input type="text" id="nombre_completo"
           class="form-control text-center"
           placeholder="INGRESE SU NOMBRE COMPLETO" value="">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
    <p class="notificacion"></p>
</div>
```

**El Jquery :**

```
$(function () {
    $("#nombre_completo").autocomplete({
        source: 'php/cliente_like.php',
        minLength: 1,
        width: 460,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
```

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un _fragmento de código_ (o [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)) para replicar el error?

Comment: La pregunta está etiquetada con CSS, el problema podría ser posicionamiento en CSS... pero no se incluye ni una línea de CSS en la pregunta. Por favor, añade el CSS relevante y, si es posible, crea un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Al elemento padre del input tiene que tener una posición 'relative'. En este caso quedaría así.

```
 div.col-sm-12 {
   position: relative;
 }
```

y el elemento HTML donde se va a mostrar los resultados del autocomplete tiene que tener posición absoluta. Quedaría así.

```
   div.autocomplete {
     position: absolute;
     /* En cuanto a la altura pues pones lo que quieras*/
    top: 0;
     left: 0;
   }
```